# can I assign "pass" keyword to a variable/name?

Tags: python-3.x

Question: Is it possible to assign 'pass' keyword to a variable?
If not possible please explain me why ?

```
def validate_password(first_pwd, second_pwd):

    vowels = [a,e,i,o,u]
    first_length = len(first_pwd)
    second_length = len(second_pwd)
    passed_test = pass   #<----- This bit here#
    # pwd length
    # is password length over 8 characters?
    if first_length >= 8:
        passed_test
    else:
        print("Password too short")
        # are the passwords the same
        if first_pwd == second_pwd:
            passed_test
        else:
            print("Password Mismatch")
            # are the passwords first and last character different
            if first_pwd[0] != first_pwd[-1]:
                passed_test
            else:
                print("First Charater cannot be same as the last character")





# CODE TESTING AREA #
password1 = "abcd1234"
password2 = "abcd1234"
print(validate_password(password1, password2))

^ Return False ^ invalid password

password1 = "Abcd1234"
password2 = "Abcd1234"
print(validate_password(password1, password2))

^ Return True ^ Valid Password

password1 = "Abedi23a"
password2 = "Abedi23a"
print(validate_password(password1, password2))

^ Return False ^ invalid password

# CODE TESTING AREA #
```

[Psudo Code](https://pastebin.com/gEsZVDvZ)

if its not possible to put the 'Pass' inside a variable ill just have to leave a  comment that tells me what it does

Comment: Not cleaner, rather more complicated thus harder to follow/understand.

Comment: oh. ok, but for me it seems to be slightly easier when im going through my code

Comment: What's your actual question? Of course you can put any sort of data into a variable and pass it around / process it - that's the whole point of programming.

Comment: Your last if statement is missing a body, also isn't this abit over engineered in general?

Comment: You could define a function named passed_test, that does nothing.t

Comment: What exactly do you want this function to do OP?

Comment: i changed my question so hopefully its more specific on what its ment to do. if its not possible to get the 'pass' into a variable how would i make a variable to bypass that part of the code and continue down the file.

Comment: Can you write some pseudocode for what you want it to do? The nested statements are very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) is a reserved keyword in Python. It cannot be assigned directly to any variables.
For more meaningful you can simple assign None to it

```
passed_test=None
for x in range(2):
    passed_test
```

In vowels the literal should be surrounded by quotes.

str.isalpha() method checks whether the string consists of alphabetic characters only

```
import re
def validate_password(first_pwd, second_pwd):
    first_length = len(first_pwd)
    second_length = len(second_pwd)
    tmp=first_pwd.lower()
    # pass = pass   #<----- This bit here#
    # pwd length
    if first_length < 8:
        print("Password too short")
    elif first_pwd != second_pwd:
        print("Password Mismatch")
    elif tmp[0].isalpha() and tmp[-1].isalpha() and \
        tmp[0] == tmp[-1]:
        print("First Charater cannot be same as the last character")
    elif len(re.findall('[aeiou]',tmp))>2:
        print("More than 2 vowels")
    elif not re.search(r'[a-z]',tmp):   
        print("No alphabetic character")
    elif first_pwd in (first_pwd.upper(),tmp):
        print("All Characters are in same case")
    else:
        return True
    return False





# CODE TESTING AREA #
password1 = "abcd123"
password2 = "abcd123"
print(validate_password(password1, password2))

password1 = "abcd1234"
password2 = "abcd1244"
print(validate_password(password1, password2))


password1 = "Abedi23a"
password2 = "Abedi23a"
print(validate_password(password1, password2))

password1 = "abed123o"
password2 = "abed123o"
print(validate_password(password1, password2))

password1 = "12345789"
password2 = "12345789"
print(validate_password(password1, password2))

password1 = "abcd1234"
password2 = "abcd1234"
print(validate_password(password1, password2))

password1 = "Abcd1234"
password2 = "Abcd1234"
print(validate_password(password1, password2))
# CODE TESTING AREA #
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot - `pass` is a statement, not a value. It's as if you want to assign `return` to a variable.

That being said, why would you even want to assign a statement that basically means `nothing` or `ignore` to anything? If you don't want something to execute, don't invoke it in the first place:

```
def validate_password(first_pwd, second_pwd):

    vowels = [a,e,i,o,u]
    first_length = len(first_pwd)
    second_length = len(second_pwd)

    # pwd length
    if first_length < 8:
        print("Password too short")
    elif first_pwd != second_pwd:
        print("Password Mismatch")
    elif first_pwd[0] == first_pwd[-1]:
        print("First Charater cannot be same as the last character")
    elif first_pwd[0].isalpha(vowels) != first_pwd[-1].isalpha(vowels):
        # this is incomplete code there is a bunch that follow but i didnt put in here#
        pass
    else:
        print("All is good!")
        return True
    return False
```